# Phoenix/Elixir - validate_format() failing for integer

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix app, I am trying to use `validate_format()` on one of my changesets to make sure that an optional integer value is not negative, if it has been provided.  However, I'm getting an error back when using the method, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my schema and changeset - since `:duration` is already defined as an integer, I'm really only concerned about making sure it does not include a minus sign:

```
embedded_schema do
  field :content, :string
  field :title, :string
  field :duration, :integer

  timestamps()
end

def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:id, :content, :title, :duration])
  |> validate_length(:title, max: 99, message: "Title must be less than 100 characters.")
  |> validate_format(:duration, ~r/[^-]\d+/)
end
```

If I try to submit the value of `-1`, for instance, this returns the error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Kernel.=~/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:1629: Kernel.=~(-1, ~r/[^-]\d+/)
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1357: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Changeset.validate_format/4
```

and the same error occurs with valid values, as well.

I've used `validate_format()` previously on string fields and it has worked just fine - I can't tell what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone clarify the right way to handle this function?

Comment: It's because you're trying to validate an integer and `validate_format` is for strings? You can use validate_number, https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_number/3

Comment: Oh my gosh, of course. I totally missed that. If you'd post that as an answer, I'd surely accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `validate_format` is another use case. For your particular problem I would use `validate_number`
For example:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:id, :content, :title, :duration])
  |> validate_length(:title, max: 99, message: "Title must be less than 100 characters.")
  |> validate_number(:duration, greater_than: 0)
end
```